# The intersections of two equations

Tags: functions

I have these two functions, that I must solve.

[image: The two functions]

When I plot them, I see there are 4 intersections:

$$(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1)$$

But how do you solve these??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g(x,y)=(x+y+1)(x+y-1)=(x+y)^2-1=x^2+y^2-1=f(x,y)\Rightarrow xy=0$, so their intersections are $x=0$ or $y=0$. (Your answer is just part of them.)

Comment: Your answer only show that their intersections are $x=0$ **or** $y=0$. It doesn't show all four intersection points

Comment: @Jens Jensen, no, actually you can check $(0,k)$ would always satisfy both $f$ and $g$, and similarly for $(h,0)$.

Comment: @JensJensen, if you really want the solution you mentioned, I think you actually mean you want the intersections that are in $xy$-plane, in which case you have $f(x,y)=g(x,y)=0$. Then your answer will be correct. (Notice that the points of $f,g$ will be 3-dimensional if not specified.)